# Find the order of this matrix on the group $(GL_{2}(\mathbb{C}),\cdot)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, matrices, order-theory

I have to calculate the order of the matrix 
\begin{equation}
A=
  \left( {\begin{array}{cc}
   i & 0\\
   -2i & -i\\
  \end{array} } \right)
\end{equation}

on $(GL_{2}(\mathbb{C}),\cdot)$.

I found, by calculating it doing $A^4$, that the order is $4$, but my question is:

Is there any way to prove it more formally, using its characteristic polynomial, or by another way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use the characteristic polynomial, if you want.  In this case, we calculate
$$
p(x) = x^2 + 1
$$
By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we have
$$
A^2 + I = 0 \implies\\ A^2 = -I
$$
It follows that $A^3 = -A$ and $A^4 = I$.

In general, it would be more useful to find the *minimal polynomial* of such a matrix.  In this case, the two coincide.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is to diagonalize the matrix and note that

$$A^n = Q^{-1} \Delta^n Q $$
where  $\Delta$ is the diagonal matrix contaning the eigenvalues and $Q$ the ortoghonal matrix realizing the change of coordinate. As you have $A^n = I\iff \Delta ^n = I$ you can simply calculate eigenvalues of $A$ and check for the order of $\Delta$, that is much less time consuming.